# Symfony2: set specific fallback locale for given locale

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation

how can I set a different default locale for a specific locale in symfony?

For example I want messages to appear in english when they are not available in the choosen language, but if the user is using catalan I want to display missing messages in spanish rather than english.

Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: One possible solution is to copy the translations from the spanish dictionary to the catalan dictionary. So it will display the missing translations in spanish instead of english.

Comment: Yes I thought of this solution, but the missing translations won't appear as missing in catalan, in the translation tool, if it is filled wih spanish. Thanks anyway :)